# Solution to the Schrödinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, quantum-mechanics

Let

$$\begin{cases} i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,t) = \Delta \Psi(x,t);\\
 \Psi(x,0) = \varphi(x)  \end{cases}$$
Why do physicists seek a solution of this equation in the form:
$$ \Psi(x,t) =  e^{iS(x,t)} a(x,t) $$
where  $S(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t} L(x(s),\dot{x} (s))\,{\rm d}s$, such that $L(x(s),\dot{x}(s))$ is the Lagrangian associated to the Hamiltonian which is also associated to $\Delta$ and $a(x,t)$ is the amplitude.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The action is way more important than the wave function...only $|\Psi|^2$ is relevant, whereas $S(x)$ gives you the propagator which has cool new information.

Comment: Because of technique of separation of variables.